# calldata encoding

Tags: solidity

I have been having an error with the following function call:

```
 IVault(VaultContract).depositFor(
                address(this),
                47545929749321238,
                address(this)
            );
```

Upon debuggin, I came accross with calldata of the function call. The call data for this call is:

calldata
`0xc8820f6c000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a7036926000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8eac56d395616000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260`

Can someone explain me why the calldata is encoded this way while the contract address (address(this)) is `0xd47C365127c4C63887FA11d3Df89c37A70369260`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calldata for standard solidity functions are encoded using the [contract abi](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/abi-spec.html).

```
c8820f6c
000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8eac56d395616
000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260
```

The first 4 bytes `c8820f6c` indicate the function id. In this case it belong to `depositFor(address,uint256,address)`.

Then follow the parameters.

- `000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260`, it is an address padded to 32 bytes, so it corresponds to `0xd47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260`.
- `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a8eac56d395616`, it corresponds to an uint256, so it is 47545929749321238.
- `000000000000000000000000d47c365127c4c63887fa11d3df89c37a70369260`, is also an address, and the same as the first parameter.